# New Nautilus windows open with last item in list view selected. How to change this?

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

When I open a new Nautilus/Files window (my default view set to list), the last item in the list is selected/has focus.

This is really annoying (I would much prefer the *first* item in the list was selected, or that *no* item was selected, but in any case that the list view was set to the start of the list).

**How to change this behavior without changing list view, sort order, etc.?**

Answers saying "You can't change this behavior" are acceptable.

Answers of the form "Use such-and-such window manager instead" are not not acceptable.